# C/GDB: display contents of address

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have this address, 0x8002bf20, and I need to see what's inside there. I know GDB does nice things like "print x" and I'll see something like struct ex {x: 1, y: 2}

I need to see that kind of print output for this address I need to examine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you know the type of the structure at that address, you can coerce GDB to print it with:

```
(gdb) print *(struct mystruct *) 0x8002bf20
```

If you do not know the type of the structure, then the best you can do is the `x` command which you already mentioned -- although do be aware that there's no harm in casting to the 'wrong' type, so you can try various structures with `print *(struct mystruct *)` until the output looks plausible.